# unable to send a file with <?xml> tag as an attachment using javamail

Tags: xml, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write a stream to a file and send the file as an attachment to an email using JavaMail API.

Some of the contents of the stream are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST    1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>PayloadContent</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CAFingerprint</key>
            <data>
            t5B0m0Wy7QTk78bU1C0nQsU4yAo=
            </data>
            <key>Challenge</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Key Type</key>
            <string>RSA</string>
            <key>Key Usage</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Keysize</key>
```

If I remove the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` the contents are written to the file and the file is successfully sent as an attachment.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in a blank file is sent as an attachment.

Please can someone guide as to why am I facing this issue.

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions? - Maybe some stream issues? - Does it work if the file is not streamed (taken directly from your hard drive)?

Comment: String messageTosend="your message";
message.setContent(messageToSent, "text/xml");